# Curves traced out by the centers of mass of rolling convex shapes

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curves

> **Question:**
>
> which kind of curves can be traced out by the center of mass of a rigid compact convex shape of uniform density that rolls along the x-axis without slip?
>
> Formulatd differently: are there necessary and sufficient conditions that decide whether a given curve can be generated by the center of mass of rolling shape as described above?

Examples:

- circular disks generate a horizontal line
- the convex hull of two unit-disks in contact generate a sequence of cycloidal arcs
- line-segments generate a sequence of half-circles

Comment: This paper may partially answer your question: "The Geometry of Rolling Curves."
*The American Mathematical Monthly* 88(6) June 1981 .
[JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2321826?origin=crossref&seq=1). They do not insist on the center of mass, but just an arbitrary "tracing" point.